Can't run my flutter project on physical mobile device
When I execute a command 'flutter run' in terminal to debug my project then it generate apk on my android device but show black screen (although I have proper project code).
I tried it with 2 separate projects but facing the same problem.While debugging I face 3 warning but these are not the main problem because in my last windows I debugged my projects while these warning were there, although many lines appear with words "Bridge call failed" in each one. This don't understand this thing (maybe the cause of error)

Can you show us your 'proper' code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The problem is not with the code because I'm facing this even with default counter app code

What is the physical mobile device and what version of Android is it running?

Here is a list of things that may help.

Ensure your Flutter setup is correct by running flutter doctor
Check Your main.dart and other dart files for errors
Run flutter run -v and look for errors in the log output (e.g., missing assets, build failures, or runtime errors).
Run flutter clean then repeat step 3.
Run flutter pub get to get the package's dependencies then repeat step 3.

